# PHP : verify JWS with JWK (x5c)

Tags: php, jwt, symfony5, jwk

Context: I want to implement payment with Payconiq. When the payment is done, Payconiq calls my API to give me payment information (status, etc).

I'm using Symfony and web-token/jwt-bundle to verify JWS.

1/ I use 'base64_decode' to get the header from the token (token format is like: header.payload.signature with an empty payload)

2/ I get the json JWKs from URL: the JWK that always seems to be used is like:

```json
{
      "kty": "EC",
      "use": "sig",
      "x5t#S256": "******************",
      "crv": "P-256",
      "kid": "kid.2021",
      "alg": "ES256",
      "x5c": [],
      "x": *******,
      "y": *******
```

3/ I want to verify the signature with this JWK. I do :

```
$serializerManager = new JWSSerializerManager([new CompactSerializer(),]);

$jws = $serializerManager->unserialize($token);

$isVerified = $jwsVerifier->verifyWithKey($jws, $jwk, 0, $payload);
```

(public function verifyWithKey(JWS $jws, JWK $jwk, int $signature, ?string $detachedPayload = null): bool)

My payload: body request sent by Payconiq (payment information).

$isVerified is always false.

I don't know if the problem comes from my payload or the way I use the library (documentation shows an example with a JWK like

```json
{
    "kty": "oct",
    "k": "dzI6nbW4OcNF-AtfxGAmuyz7IpHRudBI0WgGjZWgaRJt6prBn3DARXgUR8NVwKhfL43QBIU2Un3AvCGCHRgY4TbEqhOi8-i98xxmCggNjde4oaW6wkJ2NgM3Ss9SOX9zS3lcVzdCMdum-RwVJ301kbin4UtGztuzJBeg5oVN00MGxjC2xWwyI0tgXVs-zJs5WlafCuGfX1HrVkIf5bvpE0MQCSjdJpSeVao6-RSTYDajZf7T88a2eVjeW31mMAg-jzAWfUrii61T_bYPJFOXW8kkRWoa1InLRdG6bKB9wQs9-VdXZP60Q4Yuj_WZ-lO7qV9AEFrUkkjpaDgZT86w2g'
}
```

There's is a "k" key and the result is ok (isVerified = true).

But with a JWK without "k" and with "x5c", isVerified still false.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the verification failed because you have have forgotten to set the appropriate signature algorithm (`ES256`) in the `$jwsVerifier` object.

Find hereafter a valid example. Please change the JWK and token values with you data.

```php
use Jose\Component\Core\AlgorithmManager;
use Jose\Component\Core\JWK;
use Jose\Component\Signature\Algorithm\ES256;
use Jose\Component\Signature\Serializer\CompactSerializer;
use Jose\Component\Signature\JWSVerifier;

$jwk = JWK::createFromJson('{"kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","x":"f83OJ3D2xF1Bg8vub9tLe1gHMzV76e8Tus9uPHvRVEU","y":"x_FEzRu9m36HLN_tue659LNpXW6pCyStikYjKIWI5a0"}');
$token = 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ.DtEhU3ljbEg8L38VWAfUAqOyKAM6-Xx-F4GawxaepmXFCgfTjDxw5djxLa8ISlSApmWQxfKTUJqPP3-Kg6NU1Q';

$serializerManager = new CompactSerializer();
$jws = $serializerManager->unserialize($token);

$algorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([new ES256()]);
$jwsVerifier = new JWSVerifier($algorithmManager);

$isVerified = $jwsVerifier->verifyWithKey($jws, $jwk, 0);
if ($isVerified)  {
    var_dump('Signature is valid');
} else {
    var_dump('Signature is NOT valid!');
}
```

In case the payload is detached from the token, you can set it as fourth parameter of the `verifyWithKey` method.
Note that it shall not be base 64 encoded.

```php
<?php

use Jose\Component\Core\AlgorithmManager;
use Jose\Component\Core\JWK;
use Jose\Component\Signature\Algorithm\ES256;
use Jose\Component\Signature\Serializer\CompactSerializer;
use Jose\Component\Signature\JWSVerifier;

$jwk = JWK::createFromJson('{"kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","x":"f83OJ3D2xF1Bg8vub9tLe1gHMzV76e8Tus9uPHvRVEU","y":"x_FEzRu9m36HLN_tue659LNpXW6pCyStikYjKIWI5a0"}');
$token = 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9..DtEhU3ljbEg8L38VWAfUAqOyKAM6-Xx-F4GawxaepmXFCgfTjDxw5djxLa8ISlSApmWQxfKTUJqPP3-Kg6NU1Q';
$payload = base64_decode('eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ');

$serializerManager = new CompactSerializer();
$jws = $serializerManager->unserialize($token);

$algorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([new ES256()]);
$jwsVerifier = new JWSVerifier($algorithmManager);

$isVerified = $jwsVerifier->verifyWithKey($jws, $jwk, 0, $payload);
if ($isVerified)  {
    var_dump('Signature is valid');
} else {
    var_dump('Signature is NOT valid!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have several algorithms in ```$jmsVerifier``` (in ```framework.yaml```), including ```ES256```.

I think the problem comes from the payload or the JWK that I may not be using correctly, I don’t know.

The token I receive doesn’t contain a payload, and I’m not sure how I should rebuild it (or even if I should actually rebuild it).

It’s a bit fuzzy I’m well aware of :/

Comment: Hi, 
To be valid, your `ES256` key shall have at least the properties `kty: "EC"`, `crv: "P-256"`, `x` and `y`.
I edited my answer to show you how to manage detached a payload (no need to rebuild anything)

Comment: Thank you for your help ! The problem was : unnecessary spaces in the payload.

Comment: Not sure why the contributor of this answer got no up votes when logic wise it's correct and the person put quite some effort to explain and write the answer well. Anyways as this is helpful answer I'm going to up vote it. Thanks @Spomky-Labs